# Como exportar e utilizar um Middleware Local com Express Route?

Tags: node.js, express.js, middleware

**Estou com duas dificuldades as quais são:**

- **1)** Estou tentando exportar e utilizar os meus **middlewares** para serem utilizados localmente.
- **2)** Gostaria de saber também se é possível utilizar um **middleware** para um tipo de requisição específica utilizando o `Express Route`.

**O que está ocorrendo na primeira dificuldade?**

Só estou conseguindo utilizar o **middleware** exportado se ele for `global`, como local nas rotas parece que ele não é chamado.

**O que está ocorrendo na segunda dificuldade?**

Qualquer tipo de requisição que estiver aninhada aquela rota chamará aquele **middleware**, porém e se eu quiser botar o **middleware** para uma rota específica que é o caso do `checkProjectPost`, como deve ser feito utilizando o `express router`?

**Index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require ('body-parser');
const routes = require('./routes');
const middleware = require('./middlewares');


const server = express();
server.use(cors());
server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// server.use(middleware.checkId);
server.use(routes);
server.listen(3000, 'localhost', () => console.log('SERVER [ONLINE]'));

module.exports = server;
```

**Routes.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();
const middleware = require('./middlewares');

router.route('/projects', middleware.checkProjectPost)
  .get((req, res) => {
    console.log("GET")
    return res.status(200).send();
  })
  .post((req, res) => {
    req.body.tasks = [];

    return res.status(200).send({ msg: 'Success, project created!' });
  });

router.route('/projects/:id', middleware.checkId)
  .put((req, res) => {})
  .delete((req, res) => {});

router.route('/projects/:id/tasks', middleware.checkId)
  .post((req, res) => {});

module.exports = router;
```

**Middlewares.js**

```
module.exports = {
  checkId: (req, res, next) => {
    const { id } = req.params;

    return (!id && typeof id !== 'string') 
      ? res.status(400).send({ errorMsg: 'The id property is empty or the type is different from string' })
      : next();
  },
  checkProjectPost: (req, res, next) => {
    console.log()
    const { id, title } = req.body;
    console.log (req)

    if (!id && typeof id !== 'string' || !title && typeof title !== 'string') {
      return res.status(400).send({ errorMsg: 'The id or title property is empty or the type is different from string' })
    } else {
      req.body.tasks = [];
      return next();
    }
  },
  showQuantityRequisition: (req, res, next) => {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está passando os parâmetros errados para os métodos.

O método `route()` do `router` recebe apenas um parâmetro: a string com a sua rota. Passar o middleware como segundo parâmetro não terá nenhum efeito, se você quer que esse middleware rode antes dos demais handlers, você pode passa-lo para o método `all()`, que sempre é disparado, não importa se a requisição é do tipo `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`.

Exemplo:

```
router.route('/projects')
  .all(middleware.checkProjectPost)
  .get((req, res) => {
    console.log("GET")
    return res.status(200).send();
  })
  .post((req, res) => {
    req.body.tasks = [];
    return res.status(200).send({ msg: 'Success, project created!' });
  });
```

Agora se você quer o middleware rodando apenas em um tipo de requisição da rota, como por exemplo no `POST`, não tem mistério, é só passa-lo como parâmetro para o `post()`, pois esse método aceitam qualquer número de parâmetro, e irá continuar rodando esses middlewares sequencialmente até que a função `next()` não seja mais invocada:

```
router.route('/projects')
  .get((req, res) => {
    console.log("GET")
    return res.status(200).send();
  })
  .post(middleware.checkProjectPost, (req, res) => {
    req.body.tasks = [];
    return res.status(200).send({ msg: 'Success, project created!' });
  });
```

Comment: Muito bom a sua resposta, era isto mesmo que precisava. Antes eu estava fazendo sem o route do express, então eu botava na direita os middlewares, porém com o express route ele não aceitava aí não entendi nada.

Answer (score 1):

Olá amigo tdb? Então pelo que eu entendi vc só está com dificuldades de implementar um middleware dentro de uma rota correto?
Se for esse o caso vc pode utilizar seu middleware da seguinte maneira seguindo este exemplo:

```
post("/registro", (req, res) => {
    var erros = []

    if(!req.body.nome || typeof req.body.nome == undefined || req.body.nome == null){
        erros.push({texto: "Nome inválido!"})
    }

    if(!req.body.email || typeof req.body.email == undefined || req.body.email == null){
        erros.push({texto: "Email inválido!"})
    }

    if(!req.body.senha || typeof req.body.senha == undefined || req.body.senha == null){
        erros.push({texto: "Senha inválida!"})
    }

    if(req.body.senha.length < 4){
        erros.push({texto: "Senha muito curta"})
    }   

    if(req.body.senha != req.body.senha2){
        erros.push({texto: "As senhas são diferêntes, tente novamente!"})
    }

    if (erros.length > 0) {

        res.render("usuarios/registro", {erros: erros})

    } else {
        Usuario.findOne({email: req.body.email}).then((usuario) =>{
            if (usuario) {
                req.flash("error_msg", "Email já cadastrado!")
                res.redirect("/usuarios/registro")
            } else {

                const novoUsuario = new Usuario({
                    nome: req.body.nome,
                    email: req.body.email,
                    senha: req.body.senha
                })

                bcrypt.genSalt(10, (erro, salt) => {
                    bcrypt.hash(novoUsuario.senha, salt, (erro, hash) => {
                        if (erro) {
                            req.flash("error_msg", "Não foi possível salvar novo usuário")
                            res.redirect("/")
                        }

                        novoUsuario.senha = hash

                        novoUsuario.save().then(() => {
                            req.flash("success_msg", "Usuário criado com sucesso!")
                            res.redirect("/")
                        }).catch((err) => {
                            req.flash("error_msg", "Houve um erro ao criar novo usuário")
                            res.redirect("/usuarios/registro")
                        })

                    })
                })

            }
        }).catch((err) => {
            req.flash("error_msg", "Houve um erro interno")
            res.redirect("/")
        })
    }
})
```

Neste exemplo eu criei um array de tratativa de erro antes de passar a função posto específica que era cadastrar novo usuário vc pode passar os dados do erro direto no responde como eu fiz
Outra maneira é criar em uma pasta separada como vc fez e passar antes da req e res por exemplo:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const eAdmin = require('../Path_do_middleware')

//Exemplo de rota X
router.get('/', eAdmin, (req, res) funcionou() {
  res.render('index')//a função vai sempre depois da rota
})
```

Comment: Olá amigo, agradeço pela paciência e boa vontade de resposta, porém a sua resposta não condiz ao que eu esperava, o usuário @user140828 respondeu a mesma perfeitamente. Gostaria de deixar aqui também algumas dicas de padronização de código para você, por exemplo: Você fez req.body.senha == null e também req.body.senha == undefined, para você verificar se esta propriedade existe não precisa comparar desta maneira, basta apenas inserir "req.body.senha" será verificado se esta propriedade existe. E a segunda dica é sobre o seu código, separe o seu projeto por boas práticas.

Comment: muito obrigado Thiago irei refatorar os meus códigos desta maneira a partir de agora, obrigado pela dica